# Variable name of variables in cyklus

Tags: python

How to do that in cyklus? I need a list of variables and match them values from another list or label them with numbers.

```
for i in range(0,10):
        variable(str[n]) = numbers[n].tolist()
```

Thank you

Comment: What on earth is cyklus?

Comment: I think OP means a loop, perhaps

Comment: Just use a container, like a list or a dict

Comment: I ment for cyklus. So it is not possible to do that in that way I have to write all variables like variable1, variable2, variable3...?